# UISearchController searchbar in a tableview header leaves status bar sized gap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using a UIViewController with a tableView.  I've setup a searchcontroller and embed the searchbar into the tableview header. When i search it leaves a status bar sized gap between the tableview and the uiview above it. I realize there are a lot of other questions on SO about this but none of them solved this problem.

Here is the code for setting up the searchbar:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = kBlueNavBarColor;
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

[image]
[image]
[image: Here is the layout of the view:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the "top" auto layout anchor of the view that holds the segment controller from "super view" to "top layout guide". this moved the gap up to where the status bar is and changing the entire view's background color to the same color blue as the navbar made it seamless.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when showing a `UIViewController` modally.  The navigation bar was going up too far.  I resized the navigation bar made it a little bit wider.  Let me know if this helps.  This issue started with iOS 7.  You might not need to check the version.

```
float currentVersion = 7.0;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion) {
        // iOS 7
        self.navBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navBar.frame.origin.x, self.navBar.frame.origin.y, self.navBar.frame.size.width, 64);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you resized the nav bar the grey still there just a bit lower?

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets