# iOS 13 - When Search Active Push to other VC then that VC UITableView goes under the NavigationBar in Swift 4

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, ios13

I have check this in iOS 12 it's working fine. Issue is when I am going to search and push to second VC it working fine. when I back and again push to second VC then UITableview goes under the NavigationBar. Normal push working fine only issue when search active and push second time.

#### I have try this below solution but none of this are working for me.

1. `UnderTopBar`
2. `forKeyPath:"hidesShadow"`
3. `edgesForExtendedLayout`
4. `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`
5. `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`
6. `self.view layout` too.

[Please check this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUODn.gif)

if anyone have answer of this and any suggestion then please tell me. Thank You.

Comment: no solution for this ? can any one pls suggestion me here ? reference link ? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

IF any one have same issue then please try this solution..

It's working for me. I hope it's working for you too.

**Objective-C**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]; 
        [self.navigationController.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
         self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()     
         self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**If this is not working then please check in OS Version 13.1.3. I think it's working.**