# How to set-up UISearchController across iOS versions?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios13, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` above a `UITableView`, popping up from a `UIButton` on a `UIViewController`.

All was well. Then iOS 11.0 came and a different set-up was needed.
And then iOS 13.0 came out and the `UISearchBar` wasn't visible in the UI. I've added a special-case: the search bar is now visible. But there is a gap between the bottom of the search bar and the top of the table. A user can scroll table rows up to fill this gap and back down to reveal the gap.

How can I get rid of this gap?

Code:

```
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            // my attempt at getting a correct setup
            self.navigationItem?.searchController = searchController
            table.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
        } else if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationItem = navigationItem
        } else {
            table.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
        }
```

Comment: Hi Carl, check out this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521967/ios-13-strange-search-controller-gap and let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: hi @Sam I saw that post. tried the answers with votes without it addressing my problem. At this point I'd like to understand how Apple intends setup to work rather than a hack around Apple's APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution came down to a timing issue of making the `searchController` the first responder.

The code in the question could be reduced back to:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem = navigationItem
} else {
    table.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
}
```

as no special-case for iOS 13 was required.

I have a function to display the search controller and results and this was:

```
// be the last claiming firstResponder otherwise,
// keyboard doesn't appear and searchBar doesn't move into navbar
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

This `async` made sense to me as the UI needed to complete before trying to set focus on the `searchBar`.

For iOS 13 (and this change is still compatible with iOS 11+) I've switched to `asyncAfter`

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

This makes me nervous because I don't know why the code needs to wait 0.01seconds before calling `becomerFirstResponder()`. This is the only `async` call in this part of my code.

If anyone knows the **why** please answer and that will truly be the correct answer! :)